# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have the following code in the main `header file`

```
NSMutableArray *array;
NSDictionary *dict,*dict1;
```

`.m` file contains array of dictionaries which display the item name along with their resp prices, I have displayed this in `UITableView`

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
      return [array count];
   }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   { 
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) 
        {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
      cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"],[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"price"]];
                    return cell;        
   }
```

when the user selects any one item it sends the `dictionary` another `dictionary` called pass to `VegQuantityViewController` where quantity has to multiplied with the price

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {           
         VegQuantity *vegetarian1 = [[VegQuantity alloc] initWithNibName:@"VegQuantity" bundle:nil];    
        vegetarian1.pass=dict;
        [self presentModalViewController:vegetarian1 animated:YES];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {           
        VegQuantity *vegetarian1 = [[VegQuantity alloc] initWithNibName:@"VegQuantity" bundle:nil];
        vegetarian1.pass=dict1;
        [self presentModalViewController:vegetarian1 animated:YES];
     }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    array=[NSMutableArray array];
    dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20.00",@"price",@"tomato soup",@"name",nil];
    [array addObject:dict]; 
    dict1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"10.00",@"price",@"Veg Manchow soup",@"name",nil];
    [array addObject:dict1];
    NSLog(@"The array of dictionaries contains%@",array);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

`VegQuantity.h`

```
NSDictionary *pass;
IBOutlet UIButton *done;
IBOutlet UITextField *input,*output;
NSNumber *prices;
float x,y,c;
```

`VegQuantity.m`

The `done` button just retrieves the key for that particular dish and multiplies it with the quantity user inputs in the `textfield` and displays it in the output `textfield`
I am facing `NSInvalidArgumentException` on pass `objectForKey` line, what can be the problem?

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{   
    prices=[pass objectForKey:@"price"];
    x=[input.text floatValue];
    y=[prices floatValue];
    c=x*y;
    output.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",c];
}
```

Comment: if you change your code to ARC, that will resolve most of these types of issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change below code in viewDidLoad method.

```
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20.00",@"price",@"tomato soup",@"name",nil];
[array addObject:dict]; 
dict1=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"10.00",@"price",@"Veg Manchow soup",@"name",nil];
[array addObject:dict1];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case array, dict and dict1 are `autoreleased` objects. Retain these member variable in the `viewDidLoad` method. Or have a retain property to these variables. It is crashing because the dict is being released. The crash says that the variable dict is of type `CFString`, which might be caused due to `autoreleasing` of that object.